# I have nested divs and need a more efficient way of selecting them

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this HTML structure that consists mainly of nested divs. I need to alternate the color based on the position of the nested div. So parent must be one color and child must be another, thus alternating depending on nested elements.

```
<div class="indent">
    <div class="indent">
        <div class="indent">
            <div class="indent">
                <div class="indent"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="indent">
    <div class="indent">
        <div class="indent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="indent">
    <div class="indent"></div>
</div>
```

And I have this CSS that I need to figure out how to improve to be more efficient for selecting the the alternating nested tags.

```css
.indent{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background:#dfdfdf;
}
.indent > .indent{
    background:#fff;
}
.indent > .indent > .indent{
    background:#dfdfdf;
}
.indent > .indent > .indent > .indent{
    background:#fff;
}
.indent > .indent > .indent > .indent > .indent{
    background:#dfdfdf;
}
```

Is there a more effient way of selecting the alternate indent nested tags cause would love to know?

Comment: You can use ids or another class depending on the level

Comment: you can try nth-child()

Comment: Really...5 levels deep? That sort of breaks the 'inception' rule :)

Comment: @Benjamin `nth-child` will not work in this instance.

Comment: Maybe you can add a class like `level-3`.

Comment: In this case it's probably better to rename your classes to things like `'indent-1', 'indent-2', 'indent-3', ` etc...

Comment: @Paulie_D yes i have tried nth-child and it doesnt work. I am working will a forum posts with replies.

Comment: This is going to need a JS/JQ solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add an extra class to the divs. Keep the `indent` class for general markup, and add classes like `level-1`, `level-2`, `level-3`, `level4`...

I don't think there is a CSS selector that lets you specify the level.

In your current setup, `indent > indent` will not only match divs of the second level, but also divs of the third and fourth level. This is not a problem as long as you overwrite all declared properties in a more specific selector, but if you want to make the font of only level 2 larger, you would have to make it smaller for level 3 explicitly.

But if you cannot add `level` classes, than that is what you have to do, since there are not better selectors to make it easier.

You can use multiple selectors like this, so you can add extra levels by only adding an extra selector:

```
.indent {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.indent > .indent,
.indent > .indent > .indent > .indent {
    background: #fff;
}

.indent,
.indent > .indent > .indent,
.indent > .indent > .indent > .indent > .indent {
    background: #dfdfdf;
}
```

Comment: I am using a plugin and dont want to alter the plugin call.

Comment: That is the most logical way...but it's likely that these classes would have to be applied with JS as I understand the requirement.

Comment: Yes i realise that, just wondering if there was a more effiecint way of doing this without using javascipt or adding classes

Comment: @Andrew_tainton In that case, I'm afraid the answer is "no".

Comment: You could simplify this a little more by giving `.indent { background: #dfdfdf; }` then using the second rule `.indent > .indent ... ` to alternate the colours to white, like above.

Answer (score 0):

If you separated your classes so that you have the original indent class and then another class which only applies a color you could clean things up quite a bit.  Here's an example:

```
<div class="indent grey">
    <div class="indent white">
        <div class="indent grey">
            <div class="indent white">
                <div class="indent grey"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="indent grey">
    <div class="indent white">
        <div class="indent grey"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="indent grey">
    <div class="indent white"></div>
</div>
```

Then your CSS you be reduced down to:

```
.indent{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.white{
    background:#fff;
}

.grey{
    background:#dfdfdf;
}
```

Alternatively, you could take advantage of the nth-child(odd) and nth-child(even) pseudo selectors.  You would need to rewrite your markup to make all your elements siblings of each other though.

Comment: @Paulie_D You are correct. nth-child will not work with the current HTML.  As I said above, you would need to restructure your markup so that `.index` elements are siblings.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a background colour with an opacity value.

Each successive level would cause the 'opacity' to reduce by accumulation of opacity values

```
.indent {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

[**Jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v3suzo45/3/)

Comment: That wouldn't alternate the backgrounds, would it?

Comment: No...but it does differentiate them and indicate a nesting level. It's an option...not a precise solution.